# Installing Windows 10 UEFI with Ubuntu already installed

Tags: dual-boot

I already have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and working fine. I was already dual booting Win 10 with GRUB, but something happened to my Windows install, I had to reinstall Windows which worked fine but GRUB WILLNOT find my Win 10 boot partition.  (EUFI install = 4 partitions)
Anyone know how to fix this.
Both systems are on their own HDD in my system.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Did you update grub after installing Windows? Would be useful to state exactly how you reinstalled Windows.

Comment: Thanks for replying,

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know how to update grub, my problem is with Grub NOT finding my UEFI installed windows. IF I install Win 10 Legacy it finds it perfectly. Since UEFI Windows uses 4 partitions even I don't know which one has the boot record. I have resorted to using Win10 Legacy since that works, just wondered if anyone knows why      OS-PROBER can't find it. thx

Comment: My bad, my Ubuntu is Ver 22.04.1LTS